# Detect if keyboard layout causes modifier collision

Tags: javascript

I recently received a bug complaint from a customer in Sweden where the default Mac keyboard layout has it that <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> makes a `@` sign. The customer informed me that also all keyboards in Finland has such a layout.

As far as I know, keyboards with US QWERTY layout or the UK QWERTY layouts have <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to make an `@` sign.
The problem lies in that I have a shortcut setup in the website which uses <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to perform a navigation.
This forces any user in Sweden/Finland to navigate whenever they want to enter an `@` sign.

Is there a way to know beforehand that the keyboard layout the user is using has "the not what I expect modifiers"? Or do I have to provide an option for them to disable navigation?
The way I detect keys at the moment (with Angular):

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  public onPublicKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.altKey) {
      switch (event.code) {
        case 'Digit2':
          // Perform the navigation
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not possible to detect a keyboard layout as keyboards do not have standardized identifiers. I guess the easiest way to somehow solve this issue is to just check if the visitor is using a Mac or not: `var isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')>=0;`. Then just make an if statement like `if (isMac)` and use something else.

Comment: Is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> combination instead a suitable option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of usability and compatibility with various operating systems I'd recommend changing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>).

However, there is also JS way to check that a user is not trying to input text into a text field.

Events bubble [up and down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained) from the element which is in focus to top-level element (BODY) waiting to be handled.

It is easy to check if event has reached it's target:

```
// check that event was not picked by inputs and bubbled up
// to the element to which it was attached (i.e. document.body)
if (event.currentTarget === event.target) {
...
}
```

[event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) refers to element to which event handler was attached (I suppose the `onPublicKeyDown` event handler is attached to BODY of the page)

[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) refers to the object to which event was dispatched (when focus is in INPUT element and user is typing text into a field it will be INPUT, if focus is not inside INPUT it'll probably be BODY of the page.

Here's working example:

```js
function onPublicKeyDown(event) {
    // check that event was not picked by inputs and bubbled up
    // to the element to which it was attached (i.e. document.body)
    if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
        if (event.altKey) {
            switch (event.code) {
                case 'Digit2':
                    // Perform the navigation
                    alert('Navigating away...');
            }
        }
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', onPublicKeyDown);
```

```html
Try press 'option + 2' when focused inside input and when outside.<br>
<input type="text" />
```